# Is there anyway to set bitmap in notification button

Tags: android, bitmap, android-notifications, android-resources

I am using `ImageLoader` to download button image but the problem is I am getting image in `Bitmap` and `Uri` and I need to set the image in **`Notification.builder.addAction()`** method which takes a `resource id`.
Full method with arguments is:

```
Notification.builder.addAction(int resId, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent)
```

So is there any way by which I can set `bitmap` or `uri` to `addAction()` method

Comment: You'll have to create a custom `Notification` for that, and set your image on the `RemoteViews` for it.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I am asking for `addAction()` method not for remote views.

Comment: Well, that's what I was saying, is that you can't with `Action`s. However, now that I think about it, I believe the recent `Action.Builder` API can handle `Icon`s, which you could create from your `Bitmap`s.

Comment: Yeah, have a look at [`Action.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action.Builder.html), and the [`Icon.createWithBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html#createWithBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) method. I've not tested this, though, and the `Icon` class was just added in API 23, so if you want to support prior versions, you're probably stuck with custom `Notification`s.

Comment: `Icon.createWithBitmap()` is for API 23 and up but not for lower API version.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned API 23, and pointed out that supporting prior versions with your design would require custom `Notification`s.